# Accessing checkboxes within a movieclip

Tags: actionscript-3, checkbox, flash-cs4

I've run into a bit of a pickle here, and am wondering if anyone could help me out.

I current have a main MovieClip (mc_investigations) on the stage, and within it are 18 checkboxes (cb_1, cb_2 etc).

On the main timeline, I'm trying to access each checkbox by using a for loop:

```
for (var i=0; i <=18; i++)
{
    var CBname = 'cb_' + i;
    if (mc_investigations.CBname.selected == true)
    {
        trace("Checkbox" + i + " is selected.");
    }

}
```

I get the error:
TypeError: Error #1010: A term is undefined and has no properties.
    at layout_fla::MainTimeline/frame1()

Which leads me to believe the variable CBname is staying as a String - how do I convince Flash that it's an instance of a checkbox, inside a MovieClip?

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
if (mc_investigations[CBname].selected == true)
```

This post may also help [getChildByName](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11674195/as3-reference-movieclip-by-name-property)

Answer (score 0):

A more robust approach if your checkboxes are exported as a custom class (e.g. `Checkbox`) would be something like:

```
for(var i:int = 0; i < mc_investigations.numChildren; i++)
{
    var child:DisplayObject = mc_investigations.getChildAt(i);

    if(child is Checkbox && (child as Checkbox).selected)
    {
        trace("Checkbox " + child.name + " is selected.");
    }
}
```